# getimagedata with original image alpha?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

On an HTML5 canvas, in javascript, I use an offscreen canvas element to draw an image onto. I then transfer a portion of this image onto another canvas onscreen. The original image is a png with an alpha channel. however by the time that the image is drawn onto the screen it's alpha channel is gone and it just has a white background.

This kind of makes sense but I cant find much out there in terms of documentation on how to sample a piece of an image, perform some action offscreen then transfer the image to an onscreen canvas with it's alpha channel intact.

Here's a little demo (appologies, it's kind of hacked out of a much bigger piece of code):

```
    //this is all nested in an MVC view, using jQuery/Backbone

    this.pasteboard = $("<canvas/>").attr("width",1200).attr("height",600)
    this.pasteboard = this.pasteboard[0].getContext("2d");
    var img     = $("<img/>");
    var t       = this;
    img.load(function(){
        t.pasteboard.save();
        t.pasteboard.clearRect(0,0,args.width,args.height)
        t.pasteboard.drawImage(this,0,0);
        log("obj args:",args)
        o.imageData = t.pasteboard.getImageData(0,0,args.width,args.height);
        t.pasteboard.restore();
        o.ready = true;
        o.trigger("ready",args);
    }).attr("src",args.src);


 // and somewhere else in the view object i use 
 this.ctx.putImageData(myimagedataobjecthere,0,0);

 // all works fine except the alpha is now white background..
```

Presumably this is because of the lack of preservation of the alpha channel between getimagedata and putimagedata?

Has anyone got any pointers on this? Like i mentioned, there wasn't any immediate documentation i could find about this...

Thanks very much indeed

A

Answer (score 0):

> The original image is a png with an alpha channel. however by the time that the image is drawn onto the screen it's alpha channel is gone and it just has a white background.

Wait, that shouldn't be the case at all. I think something is wrong elsewhere in your code if that seems to be the case.

Here's an example of drawing a transparent image onto one canvas, with stuff drawn before and after it, and then drawing that canvas onto a second canvas, keeping the transparency intact:

http://jsfiddle.net/Urutb/

In any case, alpha channel is absolutely preserved with getImageData and PutImageData, something else you're doing here must be the issue.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'm actually trying to build an animation where various image are composited on top of each other the base is jpg thene there are 3 alpha pngs getting animated on top. So I need to store the image data for ech as a separate instance. I have modified your code a bit and draw image is fine here when using drawimage :http://jsfiddle.net/EBEN4/   however when i use get/putimage data things don't have the same effect instead it just overwrites the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/GYZvU/